# Stored Procedure, update consumed and date consumed logic

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm stuck in this scenario where in I need to update the Overtime Credits of employee. Overtime Credits under `OvertimeCredits` table will be updated once a Request for Offset is approved.

**CTORequest table**

```
CREATE TABLE CTORequest
(
    CTORequestID INT
    , EmployeeID INT
    , ApproverID INT
    , CTOStatusID INT
    , DateCreated DATETIME
    , CTOStartDatetime DATETIME
    , CTOEndDatetime DATETIME
    , NoOfHours REAL
    , ReportBackToWork DATETIME
    , Reason VARCHAR(250)
    , Remarks VARCHAR(MAX)
    , DateProcessed DATETIME
)
```

**OvertimeCredits table**

```
CREATE TABLE OvertimeCredits
(
    OvertimeCreditsID INT
    , EmployeeID INT
    , OvertimeID INT
    , OvertimeCredits FLOAT
    , DateExpired DATETIME
    , IsExpired BIT
    , Consumed FLOAT
    , DateConsumed DATETIME
)
```

In a request for offset, there is a column for NoOfHours. This NoOfHours will be deducted to the `OvertimeCredits` table. Note that each employee has many entries in OvertimeCredits. Total OvertimeCredits for an employee can get by using sum from OvertimeCredits table where id is equal to employee ID.

No Need for validation if NoOfHours is greater than the sum of employee OvertimeCredits. only the update logic.

Please see this fiddle:
http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=426411d4ace6e374ddd3916a05a8f03a

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this process by creating an update trigger on the CTORequest table
for the NoOfHours column. In the body of that trigger, code your logic for the necessary actions on the table OverTimeCredits. You can find lots of sample code on this in SQL SERVER documentation.